# trying to rendering multiple components in standard DOM, using React

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I'm trying to render multiple components on 'standard' DOM.  The first
set(below) renders, but the second, identical set, does not.  Any
idea why? btw, the 'Card' component is the same as 'JunkComponent'.
Could this be a "unique id" thing?

thanks in advance

this link should best explain:

http://pastebin.com/8f7HVyyj

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create elements with same ids.
As you have two elements with id `JunkTestComponent` on your page. React renders `<JunkComponent />` only in the first one.
Also if you want to render component in the `#Card` too you should call:

```
ReactDOM.render(<JunkComponent />, document.getElementById('Card'));
```

Comment: roaiven:  I'v tried to give 'id' a unique id, which failed when used with 'unique-id-mixin'.  Where should the id be created and used?

Comment: I can't properly understand you.. For each react mounting point you should create corresponding html node. For example if you want render react component into `#Card` use `ReactDOM.render(<JunkComponent />, document.getElementById('Card'));`. If you want to use second mounting point, you should create new html node with other id, and mount component there.

Comment: Also, why are you need multiple react mounting points? For most cases, it sufficient to use one mounting point. Just create one root component and place other components inside it.

Comment: im passing getNextUid( identifier:String ) to 'id' for <Card id...> and <JunkTest...> and it still only renders the first set. any ideas?